# Convert HTML To Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

How to convert page `HTML to word` document. For example i have a web page which i need to save in word document. How to convert HTML Page to Word Document. And how to insert Page break in word document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below you can find an example to convert html to word.

It works fine and i had tested it on `MS Office 2013` and `Open Office`.

Note : For page break insert below line

```
<br clear=all style='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always'>
```

Example:

```
Dim StrLocLetterText As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Dim ObjLocHtml1 As String = "<html xmlns:v=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"" xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40""><head></head><body>"
Dim ObjLocHtml2 As String = "</body></html>"

StrLocLetterText.Append(ObjLocHtml1)
StrLocLetterText.Append(<Content within body tag>)
StrLocLetterText.Append(ObjLocHtml2)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = ""
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + <FileName> + ".doc")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(StrLocLetterText)
HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
```