# Generating document text with formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsto, word-2010

**UPDATED ATTEMPT:**

I've tried the following based on klugerama answer, but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
var entries = new List<string>();
entries.Add("some text here, ");
entries.Add("some more text here, ");
entries.Add("and even more text here. ");

foreach (var entry in entries)
{

    object newRangeStart = Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Range.End;
    Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Range.InsertAfter(entry);
    object newRangeEnd = Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Range.End;
    var newRange = Globals.ThisDocument.Range(ref newRangeStart, ref newRangeEnd);

    if (entry == "some more text here, ")
    {
        newRange.Bold = -1;
    }
}
```

First issue is that it inserts the text backwards, i.e:

> and even more text here. some more text here, some text here,

instead of:

> some text here, some more text here, and even more text here.

and the second issue is the original issue, in that bold isn't added.  I am trying to get the output to become:

> some text here, **some more text here**, and even more text here.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am trying to create an action pane which gives the user lots of options. Based on the options selected, specific text gets inserted into the document.  I have been able to create the action pane part and the text inserting part fairly quickly and easily.  But the text is inserted without any formatting.

What is the correct way to insert text which easily allows me to add formatting to the text (pro grammatically) which will be inserted in the document?

At the moment, I am doing something like this to generate the text and insert it into the document which makes it difficult to apply formatting:

```
if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText.Append("some text here, ");
}

if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText.Append("some more text here, ");
}

if (CheckBox3.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText.Append("and even more text here. ");
}

Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Text = TheText.ToString();
```

If all 3 checkboxes were checked, the output would be something like:

> some text here, some more text here, and even more text here.

Lets say I wanted the text to be inserted as follows (notice the bold):

> some text here, **some more text here**, and even more text here.

How would I do that?

I am using VS2013 to create a word document level application.

Comment: Have you tried after replacing `newRange.Bold = -1;` to `newRange.Bold = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** What is the correct way to insert text which easily allows me to add formatting to the text (pro grammatically) which will be inserted in the document?

**Answer:** You need to extract the range of the appended text and style that range. This is solved with the out parameter of the provided function below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Appends text to a range
/// </summary>
/// <param name="range">The range to append text to.</param>
/// <param name="appendText">The text to append.</param>
/// <param name="appendedRange">The range of the appended text</param>
/// <returns>
/// The range of the combined old text and the appended text
/// </returns>
private Word.Range AppendToRange(Word.Range range, string appendText, out Word.Range appendedRange)
{
    // Fetch indexes
    object oldStartPosition = range.Start;           
    object oldEndPosition = range.End;
    object newEndPosition = (int)oldEndPosition + appendText.Length;

    // Append the text
    range.InsertAfter(appendText);

    // Define the range of the appended text
    appendedRange = Range(ref oldEndPosition, ref newEndPosition);

    // Return the range of the new combined range
    return Range(ref oldStartPosition, ref newEndPosition);
}
```

The following code will append text at the end of the document and allow for styling of multiple parts of text inserts:

```
object startCharacter = 0;
object endCharacter = Globals.ThisDocument.Characters.Count;
Word.Range textRange = Range(ref startCharacter, ref endCharacter);
Word.Range styleRange;

textRange = AppendToRange(textRange , "some text here, ", out styleRange);
styleRange.Bold = 0;
styleRange.Font.Name = "Verdana";
styleRange.Font.Size = 10.0F;

textRange = AppendToRange(textRange , "some more text here, ", out styleRange);
styleRange.Bold = -1;
styleRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
styleRange.Font.Size = 10.0F;

textRange = AppendToRange(textRange , "and even more text here.", out styleRange);
styleRange.Bold = 0;
styleRange.Font.Name = "Verdana";
styleRange.Font.Size = 20.0F;
```

Or with your code example from the original question:

```
// Assumes stMainText is of type Word.Range
Word.Range styleRange;

if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText = AppendToRange(stMainText, "some text here, ", out styleRange);
    // Example styling of the inserted text below
    styleRange.Bold = 0;
    styleRange.Font.Name = "Verdana";
    styleRange.Font.Size = 20.0F;
}

if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText = AppendToRange(stMainText, "some more text here, ", out styleRange);
    // Example styling of the inserted text below
    styleRange.Bold = -1;
    styleRange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    styleRange.Font.Size = 10.0F;
}

if (CheckBox3.Checked == true)
{
    stMainText = AppendToRange(stMainText, "and even more text here. ", out styleRange);
    // Add necessary styling here
}
```

Comment: I get exception `Value out of range.` exception on this line `Range(ref startCharacter, ref endCharacter);`. Can you tell how to fix?

Comment: @HassanNisar Do you have at least 10 characters in the word document you are testing this on? Sounds like the endCharacter might be outside the bounds of characters...

Comment: Yes got that. If there is no character then start and end should be 0.

Comment: But how you assumed that OP has mentioned `stMainText` of `Word.Range` type? I think OP is referring it as `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @HassanNisar I updated the answer to no longer rely on the number of characters in the document (which was a quick mock-up to begin with to show the code working). Regarding the stMainText; The OP asked about the best way to insert formatted text into the Word-document, thus I feel this answer as it stands will be the best for archiving reasons.  If the OP adds information about the type of stMainText and how it should be used, then I'll update the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to try this out until Monday at the earliest.  The bounty time ran out.  Sorry for the automated half bounty.  I'll let you know how I get on next week.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @oshirowanen Hope it will help you. Please report back if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sbMainText.Append("<b>some more text here</b>");
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it just added the <b> tags straight into the document instead of making the text within the tags bold.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/47cs5caa%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Try this:

```
Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Bold =  Globals.ThisDocument.WordTrue;
```

For making part of text bold here is [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.bookmark.formattedtext.aspx).

Code from MSDN:

```
private void BookmarkFormattedText()
{
     int WordTrue = 1;
     this.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
     this.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
     this.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text = "This is text in the " + "first paragraph.";
     this.Paragraphs[1].Range.Words[3].Bold = WordTrue;
     Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark bookmark1 =
               this.Controls.AddBookmark(this.Paragraphs[2].Range, "bookmark1");
     bookmark1.FormattedText = this.Paragraphs[1].Range.Words[3];
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have modified `klugerama answer`, as under:

```
void FormatText()
{
   var entries = new List<string>();
   entries.Add("some text here, ");
   entries.Add("some more text here, ");
   entries.Add("and even more text here. ");

   foreach (var entry in entries)
   {
        object newRangeStart = Globals.ThisDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.End-1;
        Globals.ThisDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertAfter(entry);
        object newRangeEnd = Globals.ThisDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.End;
        var newRange = Globals.ThisDocument.Range(ref newRangeStart, ref newRangeEnd);

        if (entry == "some more text here, ")
        {                
             newRange.Bold = 1;
             //bookmark this range
             Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Bookmark bmkStart;
             bmkStart = this.Controls.AddBookmark(newRange, "RangeBookMark");
        }                
        else
             newRange.Bold = 0;
    }   
}
```

Output:

> some text here, **some more text here,** and even more text here.

Comment: I just want it to make part of the bookmark bold.  At the moment, the code produces the following text `some text here, some more text here, and even more text here.`, but I only want it to make the following bold `some more text here`.

Comment: May be 2nd link is help for that case. I am not 100% sure though.

Comment: @oshirowanen I have updated my answer. See if it fulfills your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a different `Range` object and set the `Bold` property to `True` for each insert. Since the bookmark doesn't automatically expand, you must select the inserted text, and create a *new* bookmark with the same name and add the selected text to that bookmark object. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141692%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

```
object True = -1;
foreach (var entry in YourCollectionOfEntries)
{
    var bmkRange = Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Range;
    object newRangeStart = bmkRange.End;
    bmkRange.InsertAfter(entry);
    bmkRange.Select();
    bmkRange = Globals.ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add(Globals.ThisDocument.bmkStart.Name, Selection.Range);
    object newRangeEnd = bmkRange.End; 
    var newRange = Globals.ThisDocument.Range(ref newRangeStart, ref newRangeEnd);
    if (isBoldForThisEntry)
        newRange.Bold = True;
}
```

Comment: Please see updated attempt above, based on your answer.

Comment: @oshirowanen Shoot, you're right about the backwards insertion.  I missed this remark in [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertafter%28v=office.11%29.ASPX): "Also, if the range is a bookmark, Word inserts the specified text but does not extend the range or the bookmark to include the new text." I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the following line `bmkRange = Globals.ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add(Globals.ThisDocument.bookmark1.Name, Selection.Range);`.  The error message is `The name 'Selection' does not exist in the current context`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using html to pro grammatically construct your text way you wanted and then create a word document out of the html file.

append what you want to bold with   tags.

Please refer following thread on creating a word out of html document
[Convert HTML To Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279611/convert-html-to-word-document)