# convert HTML to word format

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, office-automation

I use word automation to create a word document. I want to embed some html code in that file. how should I cnvert html tags to word document format? ( I want to keep font, bold, table  and other styles in html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279611/convert-html-to-word-document

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();  
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";  
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";  
 string strFileName = "docName" + ".doc";  
 HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);  

 StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();  
 strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head></head><body>");
 strHTMLContent.Append(htmlContent); 
 strHTMLContent.Append("</body></html>");    

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);  
 HttpContext.Current.Response.End();  
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Your code just saves some text in word! or I misunderstood it? I want to change the html style to word style... not to save the html text with it's tags in word...

Comment: The code will save the HTML formatted text to word you need to apply in-line CSS to html and then call above code... if you need to format your content in Word as per MS-Word styles then you can consider using somethisng like [OpenXML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/)

Comment: I used `sdgdbfg nf<br />gnfgn` as htmlContent and it saved `<br />` in the word! is it something wrong with my html?

Comment: you can try replacing '<br />' with '<w:br/>' in your html

Comment: I have this html : `<p style="text-align: left; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">hi <strong>every </strong>body</p>
<br />` and it get me `<p style="text-align: left; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">hi <strong>every </strong>body</p>
<w:br/>` in word document. it do'nt change any thing!

Comment: this is working now  `strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head></head><body>"); strHTMLContent.Append(htmlContent);
        strHTMLContent.Append("</body></html>");`  add these lines to your code

Comment: thanks a lot ... it worked! I have another question now... Can I append an external css file to it? (I have a css file for my editor that handles the appearance of my editor content and I should make that changes in word file too)

Comment: noyou cannot append external css but you can define css classes in html style tag and apply classes to  your html